# Unicode Text Not Printing to Python Console/Terminal/Screen

Tags: python, io, python-unicode

I am trying to do some Python text-parsing programming with Hebrew (Unicode) text from the Torah.

Here is link to the example text (Genesis) that I am using from Sefaria.org:
https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-Export/blob/master/json/Tanakh/Torah/Genesis/Hebrew/Tanach%20with%20Text%20Only.json

I am able to successfully import the JSON data.

I do the usual data extract tests + TEST OUTPUTS WITH PRINT() to examine the data.

In the following code below, I notice that only the output for KEYS stays on screen/terminal/console.  All the other data (VALUES, ITEMS, and the VALUE for the dictionary key 'text') all disappear from the screen (please run the code with the data and see for yourself).

I figure this is some sort of encoding or decoding issue because any text with the Hebrew text (e.g. VALUES, ITEMS, and VALUE for the dictionary key 'text'), so I did standard sys check and printed the following output:

```
sys.stdin.encoding =  cp1252
sys.stdout.encoding =  cp1252
```

I figure that I may need to define/encode/decode or do something to allow written output of UTF-8 UNICODE characters (Hebrew) to the Python terminal.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

```
## IMPORT NECESSARY MODULES
import json
import sys

## CHECK ENCODING AND PRINT/TEST OUTPUT
print("sys.stdin.encoding = ", sys.stdin.encoding)
print("sys.stdout.encoding = ", sys.stdout.encoding)

## READ JSON FILE & IMPORT DATA - UTF8 CODING TO READ HEBREW TEXT
json_data = open('DATA_1GENESIS.json', encoding="utf8").read()

## LOADS AND TRANSFORMS JSON DATA TO PYTHON DICTIONARY OBJECT
DictionaryData = json.loads(json_data)
print('\n')
print("IMPORTED JSON DATA TYPE = ", type(DictionaryData))

## LOOP THROUGH DATA AND PRINT
for item in DictionaryData:
    print("ITEM = ",item, type(item), len(item))    

## TEST OUTPUT
print('\n')
print("IMPORTED DICTIONARY DATA = ",DictionaryData,    type(DictionaryData),len(DictionaryData))

## EXTRACT DICTIONARY KEYS - 'dict_keys' object
k = DictionaryData.keys()
print('\n')
print("KEYS = ",k,type(k),len(k))

## EXTRACT DICTIONARY VALUES - 'dict_values' object
v = DictionaryData.values()
print('\n')
print("VALUES = ",v,type(v),len(v))

## EXTRACT DICTIONARY ITEMS - 'dict_items' object
i = DictionaryData.items()
print('\n')
print("ITEMS = ",i,type(i),len(i))

## EXTRACT VALUE FOR KEY 'text' = DictionaryData['text']
text = DictionaryData['text']
print('\n')
print("TEXT = ", text, type(text), len(text))
```

**EDIT**

I just did a test to test simple printing of one line only of the Unicode Hebrew.  Here is the code and it worked perfectly to print output to Python screen/terminal/console.  So question remains:  why would those extracted values from the dictionary above disappear after printing to screen (please try the code with the data to see for yourselves!)?

```
x = "בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ"
print("x = ",x)
```

Comment: if terminal use `cp1252` then you have to change configuration in terminal or change terminal

Comment: How to change configuration?

Answer (score 4):

That is probably not because of your encoding, since `python 3` uses `utf-8` as default.

More probable issue is that your console uses the font `consolas` which has no hebrew support.

Change to a font like `courier new` to show the hebrew characters in the console.

---

On windows - simply hit the icon on top of the window (should be up-left or up-right if your windows is hebrew).

Then hit properties (הגדרות) and choose the font you want (I recommends `courier new`).

## EDIT

The problem seems to be the use of the character `\u05be` (מקף) in the text. I tried the following when loading the file and it worked as it should:

```
json_data = open('DATA_1GENESIS.json', encoding="utf8").read().replace('\u05be', '')
```

Comment: what characters do you see? question mark? or gibrish?

Comment: Please see EDIT above.  The test print works fine when I just placed the Hebrew text in a simple string.

Comment: I used your code, but still it does not address the problem that I described of disappearing output from the Python screen/console/terminal.  Why do you say that it worked as it should?  What worked in your proposed solution?

Comment: Did you copy/paste my code and attempt to see the problem with disappearing output as I described?

Comment: yes. printed out all of it, along with the hebrew text

Comment: Impossible to print out if you copied my code (even with your code added).  Does the output disappear for you like it does for me?